# XLST query to remove unwanted element in returned XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, scripting

I have an amended XSLT query thats returning everything I want but with an additional element i do not want there. how can i amend it so it get rid of the `<identifier type="nt">80df0b42de8f31ac4cb7a30d325ff0c1</identifier>` line. the xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CMDBTopology>
<Objects>
<CMDBSet>
<name>80df0b42de8f31ac4cb7a30d325ff0c1</name>
<CMDBObject>
<identifier type="nt">80df0b42de8f31ac4cb7a30d325ff0c1</identifier>
<Properties>
<root_class type="STRING">nt</root_class>
<host_servertype type="STRING"></host_servertype>
<host_osrelease type="STRING"></host_osrelease>
<display_label type="STRING">pharsm-s3004</display_label>
<host_osinstalltype type="STRING"></host_osinstalltype>
</Properties>
</CMDBObject>
```

and the xlst query that i have at the moment is `

```
        <html>

          <head>

                    <title> title </title>

          </head>

          <body>

                    <xsl:apply-templates />

          </body>

        </html>
```

```
        <table width="1" border="1" >

                                            <tr>
```

```
    <td> <xsl:value-of select="display_label" /> </td>      
    <td> <xsl:value-of select="root_class" /> </td>
```

```
                                <td> <xsl:value-of select="resolver_group" /> </td>

                                <td> <xsl:value-of select="supported_by" /> </td>

                                <td> <xsl:value-of select="environment" /> </td>

                                <td> <xsl:value-of select="site_code" /> </td>

                                <td> <xsl:value-of select="sla_classification" /> </td>

                                <td> <xsl:value-of select="datacenter" /> </td>
```

```
                                </tr>

        </table>
```

`

Comment: The XSLT you posted is incompatible with the XML fragment. It won't output anything (the elements it's selecting don't exist in the XML file or in the context where they are being called). Edit the question and include the actual file you are using.

Comment: I have edited it to reflect the xml file

Comment: but if i change it to the correct "value-select" it doesnt run it gives a null result but if i run it as it was before it give the correct data but with the extra element i wanted to get rid of ...

Comment: You have a template matching `CMDBRelation` in your XSLT, but no such element exists in your XML, and so this template will never get used. It might actually be more helpful if you also showed the output you are currently getting, and the output you actually want. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to change the CMDBRelation to CMDBObject and it gave the same output....i will edit the question to add the output i want and what i am getting..its compleltely omitting the table format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a precise answer, not knowing exactly what you want your output to look like, but your main problem is that you have a template matching `CMDBRelation` in your XSLT, like so...

```
<xsl:template match="CMDBRelation" >
```

But there is no such `CMDBRelation` element in your XML! This means this template will never get called. This means, when you do `<xsl:apply-templates />` in your first template, then XSLT's "built-in templates" are being used. These effectively iterate over all nodes in the XML, outputting text nodes where they find them, which is why you get all the text printing out and no table formatting.

I suspect your template actually needs to match `CMDBSet`

```
<xsl:template match="CMDBRelation" >
```

You also seem to be referring to `To` and `From` elements in your `xsl:for-each` statements, and as before, such elements don't exist in your XML.

```
<xsl:for-each select="To/CMDBObject/Properties">
```

It is possible you need to combine the two statements into one, like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="CMDBObject/Properties">
```

Here is some amended XSLT to start you off, that does produce a table and doesn't output any `identifier` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title> title </title>
         </head>
         <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="CMDBSet">
      <table width="1" border="1">
         <xsl:for-each select="CMDBObject/Properties">
            <tr>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="display_label"/></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="root_class"/></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="host_servertype"/></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="host_osrelease"/></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="host_osinstall"/></td>
            </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you very much its gotten rid of the identifier element, now i just have to twick it a bit because its now only displaying root class and display label. But this has given me a good starting point

Comment: one more question i am now trying to only show the headers once for the value-of each selected statement how can i achieve this..

Comment: Please do not edit questions after they have been answered and accepted, as it makes it hard for others to understand what is going on. It would be better if you edited your question to what it was previously, and ask a whole new question. Thank you.

Comment: okay I will edit it to the original question didnt take into consideration others might have similar questions in future